# Qt/QML: Display an indicator depending on if something is downloaded or not

Tags: qt, qml

I'm wondering what might be the best approach to the following situation:

I have a QML file that is  load from a HTTP server to a Qt/QML android app to display the UI.

The user can tap on thumbnails of catalogs and make the app download another QML file for each catalog. The catalog QML is downloaded and stored on the device for offline use.

This means I have a number of directories that have a unique ID to store the catalog QML and assets. Something like this:

```
/my/app_data_path/catalogs/CATALOG_001
/my/app_data_path/catalogs/CATALOG_007
/my/app_data_path/catalogs/CATALOG_010
```

In the UI I'd like to show an indicator that tells if a catalog has been downloaded already to the device. What would be the best approach within QML to show/hide an indicator depending on that?

```
Rectangle { 
    id: indicator
    visible: MyApp.catalogIsLoaded('some ID here') 
}
```

This is something that came to my mind, but I don't think it's the best way to do this since I'd need a method to pass the catalog ID in order to check if the data directory exists. Also I'd have to figure out a way to re-evaluate the visible state/call the `catalogIsLoaded` method from time to time - especially after downloading or deleting catalogs.

Is there a better/cleaner approach to this?

Comment: What is MyApp ? You need a model to store whether this particular catalog is downloaded. The model can have a Q_PROPERTY(bool) that you bind to visible. You set the property to true upon downloading the catalog. set it to false upon deletion of the files (if ever)

Comment: Side note: Be aware that anyone who hacks your HTTP has (at least) full read access to any file stored on the user's device (http://www.mobilephonedevelopment.com/qt-qml-tips/#File%20Access). You might want to get data in a more structured way (e.g. JSON) or in a more sandboxed way (HTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to associate your indicator visibility with a property binding.

As you wish to find a catalog by its id, provide an invokable method on your 'MyApp' class to return a catalog reference.

```
Q_INVOKABLE Catalog* findCatalogById(const QString& id);
```

Catalog will be a QObject, expose a isLoaded property to QML.

```
class Catalog : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool isLoaded READ isLoaded NOTIFY isLoadedChanged)

    public:
    Catalog(QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
    }

    bool isLoaded() const { return m_isLoaded; }
    void setIsLoaded(bool loaded) {
        if (m_isLoaded != loaded) {
            m_isLoaded = loaded;
            emit isLoadedChanged();
        }
    }

signals:
    void isLoadedChanged();

private:
    bool m_isLoaded; //should probably be initialized to false
};
```

Of course, the catalog reference provided by your context should be memorize somewhere (like in a `QHash<QString, Catalog*>`), and be updated accordingly when its status changed.